# Is it possible to use adapter as a charger?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, electrical

I have a 8V battery and a 5v,600mA output adapter.
so i needed to charge the battery using this adapter,is it possible?

when i connect my battery to adapter, the adapter power led is glow.
is it safe? why this happens?

any other way?

i am using a lithium ion battery pack(8v,2000mAh)

why lead acid battery can possible charge without protection circuit ?

thanks.

Comment: Yes it's possible, no you can't just plug the battery straight into it without any electronics.

Comment: No it is not possible to charge a 8V lithium battery with a 5V power supply. At least not without a lithium battery charger between them, that can take 5V in and charge 8V lithium batteries.

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible?

No. 5 V < 8 V so no charge will flow into the battery.

> is it safe?

No. Lithium batteries are explosive.

> any other way?

Yes. Buy a proper charger. This will monitor the battery's state of charge and limit voltage and current to a safe value to prevent fire and explosion.

> ... lithium iron battery ...

Are you sure it's not lithium-ion?

Comment: sorry it is  lithium ion battery.